# Camera will not shut off in my loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm following the article [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-picamera/worksheet/) but it seems that when I run this loop the camera does not shut off, and requires me to manually power down the unit to get out of the program. Even holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> does not exit the program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
camera.start_preview()
for i in range(5):
    sleep(5)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image%s.jpg' % i)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Adding `camera.close()` does not help.

```
camera.start_preview()
for i in range(5):
    sleep(5)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image%s.jpg' % i)
camera.stop_preview()
camera.close()
```

Comment: had you tried to just do? `camera.start_preview()` and then `camera.close()`

Comment: that did the trick. pls post as an answer i will accept it. i appreciate your help

Comment: done. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hi @holletrain, don't forget to accept if it truly helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the following without anything else?

```
camera.start_preview() 
camera.close()
```

It should do the trick